# Quarkus mongodb panache way to do $nin

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

Is it possible to do $nin queries in panache simplified query. The mongo syntax is

`Syntax: { field: { $nin: [ <value1>, <value2> ... <valueN> ] } }`

I have tried a few things but am not getting anywhere for example

`"claimentId = ?1 AND processingOrganisation = ?2 AND status = ?3 " + "AND claimId nin ?4 "`

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: In the end I dropped the panache simplified query and used a native one instead 'claimId': {$nin : [?4]}

Comment: It should be doable to translate NOT IN to $nin.
Can you open an feature request for that in the Quarkus GitHub repository?
But of course, switching to native query will work.